# Count the number of intervals that fall in the given range

Tags: algorithms

Let me explain the question suppose there are Range [1,10] and the provided intervals are (1,3),(1,8),(2,4),(2,5),(2,3),(3,9),(3,8),(3,6)   and ask to find out the number of intervals that fall'a between the ranges [1,5] the answer is 4. These are four  [(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,3)] intervals that fall's in the range [1,5]. same as if there are Range[1,N] and i provide you the intervals ,then how to find out that how many intervals are in the given range. in O(logn) Complexity or better than this ?

Comment: When you provide us with the intervals, are they already sorted (according to each interval's upper bound)?

Comment: No interval's are not already sorted

Comment: i m not counting the complexity of sorting the intervals

Comment: Hmm. Then I don't really see how it can be done in $O(\log n)$ time. The best I can think of is a naive $\Theta(n)$ algorithm that keeps track of a counter and works as follows: for each interval of the form $(a,b)$, if $b \leq N$, then the counter is incremented.

Comment: what is your O(n) complexity

Comment: i ask for many ranges can you answer all the queries in O(n)

Comment: You have to look at each interval to decide if it is in the range. So, if there are $n$ intervals, this task will take at least $O(n)$ time.

Comment: Possibly a better question for http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 5):

You can build the [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) of the input intervals. Following, you can execute a range query (i, j) that returns all intervals that overlap with (i, j)
in O(logn + k) time, where k is the number of overlapping intervals, or a range
query that returns the number of overlapping intervals in O(logn) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in O(log n) as follows, using two binary searches per query.

PRE-PROCESSING:
1. Add the end point of each interval to a list called pos_end. pos_end should initially contain -1 as a dummy element (assuming all interval end points are positive).
2. Add the start point of each interval to a list called pos_start.
3. Sort pos_start and pos_end if they are not already sorted.

QUERY:
Let [L, R] be the range you are querying. The answer (number of all intervals that are completely contained by [L,R]) is:
lower_bound(R, pos_end) - upper_bound(L, pos_start)
 
lower_bound(x, pos) returns index of first element in array pos that is smaller than or equal to x.
 
upper_bound(x, pos) returns index of first element in array pos that is greater than or equal to x.

All you have to do is  to implement the lower_bound and upper_bound functions using binary search. The std functions in C++ with the same names don't return exactly same values as those described here.

Comment: i don't think this is right:
input intervals groups:
``#1: (1,3) (4,6)``
``#2: (1,6) (3,4)``
q:(2,5)
correct answer for #1:` 0`
correct answer for #2:` 1`
this algo doesn't handle differently the two cases

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. My algo works only if the intervals in the set don't intersect. I had used that algo in another problem, where the intervals were separate.